# Python FileDialog to Get Folderpath not file

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I am using Python 3.6.  I also use PyQt.  I use Qt Designer to develop a form.  But I need a code to open a filedialog box, allow the user to navigate to the desired FOLDER (not file) and then click and print/get the folderpath.  I cannot find how to do this.  I appreciate anyone's help here.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `getExistingDirectory()` method of `QFileDialog` by applying the necessary filters:

```
import sys

from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore

app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

directory = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(None, 
    "Select Directory",
    QtCore.QDir.currentPath())

print(directory)
```